# asp.net gridview selectbutton does not postback for some clients

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

We have an ASP.net 3.5 WebForms application using VB.Net which has been running for many years. In this application there is a gridview select button that does not postback for some clients. This problem started occurring for some of our client when we moved the web application to IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008R2 from Windows Server 2003.

The select button is defined in the gridview with `asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"` 
which generates code as follows (copied from HTML source):

```
a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$bodyContentPlaceHolder$GridView1','Select$0')" style="color:#333333;">Select</a>
```

For some Win XP, Win 7 users who use IE (various releases), it does not postback when the user clicks the generated button. All users have been checked to ensure that javascript is enabled. For other Win XP, Win 7 users who use IE and other browsers, it works fine.
Much googling has turned up information about Javascript postback problems, but nothing seems to fit.

Other information: The whole gridview row is enabled for postback with this code in the GridView Rowdatabound event:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:__doPostBack('" + Replace(GridView1.ClientID, "_", "$") + "','Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString + "')")
```

which generates this HTML:

```
<tr align="center" valign="top" onClick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$bodyContentPlaceHolder$GridView1','Select$0')"
```

Note that the Javascript reads identically to the javascript which does not work, except that clicking elsewhere in the row DOES work for all users. This brings me to three possible issues:

1. Is there something about the SELECT button being in a link tag that makes it fail for some users?
2. Is there a user setting that might be different?
3. Is it something the Internet Provider is blocking?

Comment: can you edit this please so we can read it? using code blocks and paragraphs does wonders for us helping you.

Comment: Which version of IE?  Different versions introduce different problems.  From your bullet list above, all code is run from the client browser so pt 1 will be a browser issue (if the select worked before), pt 2 (no IE setting will block a postback unless they turn off javascript, pt3 (not possible for an isp to block anything).  So it could be javascript setting for the browser is off or its an IE6/7/8  or 9 issue (but we need to know which browsers).

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Is there something about the SELECT button being in a link tag that makes it fail for some users?

It seems unlikely, since the page should be rendered the same way for all users (unless you're doing client detection that you didn't disclose).

> 2.Is there a user setting that might be different?

Maybe. Things that I would look for include:

1. Check the Compatibility View Settings to find different settings (try this during development, as well).
2. Check whether users have add-ons that could interfere (run `iexplore.exe -extoff` to run IE without add-ons)
3. Force IE to ignore the cached pages (I find the easiest way to do this with IE7 and up is to press F12 for the Developer bar, and choosing "Always Refresh from Server" on the Cache menu).

> 3.Is it something the Internet Provider is blocking?

I doubt this very strongly.

Comment: Apologies for not knowing how to format properly, will study that, thanks to whoever did it.  
It works OK in IE8/XP, IE9/Win7, waiting to hear from users what versions they are on (one user has two computers, works on Win7, not on XP). Will also get them to turn off/on compatability view as a test. thanks so far

Comment: Users are using WinXP/IE8. We have both fail and success in that environment (different computers).  Compatability settings make no difference.  @Rob the javascript setting is enabled in all cases (asp.net webforms requires it). Will conduct caching and add-on test when possible.